# How do I only display a page if conditions are met i.e. if current logged in user is an admin?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

This is more of a syntactical question than anything. Can't seem to figure out the syntax to write out this proof of concept. I currently have a *RoR / psql* database that users can sign up for and log in to. A few forms are restricted for admins (user accounts are not admins by default).

The actual tab in the navigation header that leads to the form should be visible to all users. Regular users can even click through, but the page they are directed to should omit the form altogether and inform them that access has been denied. Below is the idea of what I'm trying to do. For simplicity, the actual form contents has been omitted.

Below is **/app/views/parts/new.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <%= if current_user.admin? %>
      <div class= "container">
        <!-- form content  -->
      </div>
    <%= else %>
      <div class ="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Access Denied.</strong> Page requires admin status.
      </div>
    <%end%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is **/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'sessions#new'
  get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/add/parts', to: 'static_pages#part'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'


  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  #users can generate new passwords (reset), and change them 
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :inquires,  only: [:new, :create]
  resources :parts
end
```

Below is **/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

html{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

body{
    padding: 80px;
}

header {
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
}

.nav {
    background: #232323;
    height: 60px;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}

#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #494949;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color: white;
}
#search_text:focus {
    background: #5a5a5a;
}

#options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}

.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
#options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class= "nav">
      <li><a class="active" href="/home">Home</a></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_path(current_user.id) %></li>
      <li id= "options">
        <a href="#">Add</a>
        <ul class= "subnav">
            <li><%= link_to "Part", new_part_path%></li>
            <li><a href= "/add/projects">Project</a></li>
            <li><a href= "/add/vendors">Vendor</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_part_path(current_user.id) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li>
      <li id= "search">
        <form action= "" method= "get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id= "search_text" placeholder="Search Page"/>
            <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the **users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  #must be logged in to make changes    
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def index
     @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user= User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end

  def new
    @user= User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info]= "Account created. Check your email to activate it."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile successfully updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit' #false, so render the same edit page
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User successfully deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    #users must be logged in to view content
    def logged_in_user
        unless logged_in?
            store_location #store location for after user logs in -> can access 
            flash[:danger]= "Log in to continue."
            redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    #users can only edit their own profiles
    def correct_user
        @user= User.find(params[:id])
        unless current_user?(@user)
        flash[:danger]= "You do not have permission to do that."
        redirect_to root_url 
      end
    end

    #check for admin status
    def admin_user
      unless current_user.admin?
        flash[:danger]= "Access denied. Not admin."
        redirect_to(root_url) 
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is/isn't working? BTW, you don't use `=` on ruby logic in erb (e.g., `<%= if ... %>`). `=` is for inserting content on view.

Comment: This should be working, as long as `current_user` returns an object that respond to the `admin?` method.

Comment: BTW, remember to check on the server-side too on form submission that `current_user.admin?` before performing the actual action.

Comment: It might be a routing problem? It says the page does not exist. Let me edit my question to provide more information and code.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually the best way to handle this is to not do it in the view at all.

Instead you should handle the authorization logic in the controller and use a `before_action` filter to redirect the user to the login or somewhere else that makes sense for your application.

This avoids duplicating the authorization logic in different parts of the MVC stack - it also lets you send an appropriate response code which tells robots not to index / retry the page.

Comment: Yes. And note that `/app/views/parts/new.html.erb` should not include `html` or `body` tags; it is only meant to be the part of the page that is different from other pages. When the page is rendered, it embeds the corresponding view within the [current layout](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts) template.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `=` from your `<% %>` blocks that have logic such as `if` and `else`. Only use `<%= %>` blocks for a self-contained variable or function call that returns a value by itself.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <% if current_user.admin? %>
      <div class="container">
        <!-- form content  -->
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Access Denied.</strong> Page requires admin status.
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This didn't do it. I updated my question to include some more information. Perhaps it is a routing problem..